# How to login web-form using qt5

Tags: networking, web, authentication, qt5, command-line-interface

What I'm doing is cli multiple IP checker, if its online login to its html form using: 
input type="text" name="username" id="username";
input type="password" name="password" id="password"
and get value of few attribute but stuff like network.post(request, loginData) or similar which embedding username and password to the link somehow doesn't work, I need something like Mechanize approach, but ist only available in Ruby and Python. Any help appreciated, bunging my head on this few weeks, didn't get that done...

**Here is a form code:**

```
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="loginsubtable">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="/login.cgi">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/130830.1622/images/airos_logo.png"></td>
        <td class="loginsep">
                <input type="hidden" name="uri" id="uri" value="/" />
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="logintable" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <div id="errmsg" class="error">

                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Username:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" maxlength="128"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td class="submit" align="right">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
```

**Update for the question:**

I have wrote small multipart/form-data contains form itself and action file for testing the code below:

**1. Form:**

```
<html>   
<head>
 <title>Test Page</title>
</head>   
<body>   
    <h2>Data Collection</h2><p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="proceed.php">  
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password"/></td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**2. Action file:**

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["username"]; ?><br>
Your password is: <?php echo $_POST["password"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**3. Code to test:**

```
void MainWindow::login()
{
manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

//ssl errors ignoring
connect(manager,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)),
        this,SLOT(onIgnoreSSLErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
theurl = "http://localhost/form/";

QString userName = "usr";
QString userPassword = "pwd";

qDebug() << "Attempting to login with Username =" << userName << "and Password =" << userPassword;
m_userName = userName;

QHttpMultiPart *loginData = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart userNamePart;
userNamePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                       QVariant("multipart/form-data; name=\"username\"; filename=\""+ userName + "\""));
userNamePart.setBody(userName.toUtf8());

QHttpPart userPasswordPart;
userPasswordPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                           QVariant("multipart/form-data; name=\"password\"; filename=\""+ userPassword + "\""));
userPasswordPart.setBody(userPassword.toUtf8());

loginData->append(userNamePart);
loginData->append(userPasswordPart);

qDebug() << "OK with code1";

QNetworkRequest request(theurl);
request.setRawHeader( "User-Agent" , "Mozilla Firefox" );

qDebug() << "OK with code2";
QNetworkReply *reply = manager->post(
            request,
            loginData);

loginData->setParent(reply);
qDebug() << "OK with code3";

connect( reply, SIGNAL( finished() ),
         SLOT( _q_onLoginRequestFinished() ) );

connect( reply, SIGNAL( metaDataChanged() ),
         SLOT( _q_onLoginMetaDataChanged() ) );

}

void MainWindow::_q_onLoginRequestFinished()
{
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>( sender() );
QByteArray ba = reply->readAll();
qDebug() << ba + " request-finished->";
if ( !reply )
    return;

QList<QNetworkCookie> cookies = qvariant_cast<QList<QNetworkCookie> >(reply->header(QNetworkRequest::SetCookieHeader));
if(cookies.count() != 0){
    //you must tell which cookie goes with which url
    manager->cookieJar()->setCookiesFromUrl(cookies, theurl);
}


qDebug() << QString::number(cookies.count());

if ( ba.isEmpty() )
{
    emit loggedInAs( m_userName );
    m_isLoggedIn = true;
    emit isLoggedInChanged();
}
}

void MainWindow::_q_onLoginMetaDataChanged()
{
qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;

QNetworkReply* reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>( sender() );
if ( !reply )
    return;

QVariant statusCode = reply->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute );
if ( !statusCode.isValid() )
    return;

int status = statusCode.toInt();

if ( status != 302 )
{
    QString reason = reply->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute ).toString();
    qDebug() << QString::number(status) + " status num" ;
    qDebug() << tr( "Loging request failed: %1." ).arg( reason );
    emit loginFailed( reason );
}
if(status == 302)
{
    QUrl newUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    qDebug() << "redirected from xx to " + newUrl.toString();
    QNetworkRequest newRequest(newUrl);
    manager->get(newRequest);
    return;
}

}
```

**This code only prints html form, but should submit and print action result instead. It uses .cgi.**
**Is there a way to login through .cgi?**

Comment: theurl must point to the form's action URL, **not** the form itself.

Comment: it works for cookies free form, but how to get it work for https://localhost/login.cgi?uri=/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you did not provide the data in the correct form. Check with tools like [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org) what your program really sends to the server and if it matches your expectations.

Since there is not much else to say with that question I'll go ahead and show how to correctly send POST requests using `QNetworkAccessManager`.

*Update:* This is now for multipart forms, not normal urlencoded forms. Beware, the two are not compatible and handled completely different. You might need to adjust `.toUtf8` to match the expected encoding by the server.

```
QHttpMultiPart loginData(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart userNamePart;
userNamePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                       QVariant("form-data; name=\"username\""));
userNamePart.setBody(userName.toUtf8());

QHttpPart userPasswordPart;
userPasswordPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                           QVariant("form-data; name=\"password\""));
userPasswordPart.setBody(userPassword.toUtf8());

QHttpPart uriPart;
uriPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                  QVariant("form-data; name=\"uri\""));
uriPart.setBody("/");

loginData.append(userNamePart);
loginData.append(userPasswordPart);
loginData.append(uriPart);

QNetworkRequest loginRequest(loginUrl);

// set up QNetworkAccessManager

QNetworkReply *loginReply = networkManager->post(
            loginRequest,
            &loginData);
// note that the fully encoded representation does contain only ASCII characters

QObject::connect(loginReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [loginReply]() {
    qDebug() << loginReply->readAll();
});
```

Connect `loginReply`s finished signal to a handler to check the HTTP status and parse incoming data by using, for example, Qt's XML processing facilities. Here I just dump the servers' reply to `qDebug`.

Comment: thank you for your reply! Have used your code snipped, I've got httpstatuscode 200, and doesn't login to the html part, if it might help form contains code like this: form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="loginform" method="post" action="/login.cgi" /form

Comment: could you add the complete (`form`-tag, all fields, preferably no markup) HTML form to your question?

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your updated question. It now explains multipart forms. Due to the form being multipart everything gets way more complicated than normal. Notice that the encoding might need adjustment to the servers expectations - utf-8 should be fine... in 2014.

Comment: it parses html with 200 code but do not login... do you know how to sort this out? when passing usr and pwd, do i have to push login button somehow or its done automatically when usr and pwd received?

Comment: Check the contents of `networkManager->cookieJar->cookiesForUrl(QUrl(yourUrl))`. After the request finished there should be some session cookie or something similar. Also, do a login via your browser (disable Images, JS etc. before that) and capture it with Wireshark. Some Websites use more complicated login schemes than simple cookies (e.g. SSO). Check the headers of the network reply.

Comment: i have no idea how to do this, do you know any links for reference?

Comment: Wireshark is not very complicated: install it, start a new capture on your network card and visit the site in your browser. You should see the HTTP requests popping up in Wireshark immediately.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, i have tried to submit to the cookie free form, but it doesn't do though, please take a look at updated question.

Comment: it's keeps redirecting from cookie to cookie but never login, could you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: yes, it uses login.cgi, it means that login part is secured